# Что делать если при работе с pyinstaller возникает ошибка с кодеком?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

При попытке собрать приложение "Hello World" из py в exe выводит такую ошибку кодека: 
File

```
"c:\users\ванек\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 112-116: character maps to <undefined>
```

как это решить? Использую python 3.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в энкоде символов на позиции 112-116. По умолчанию кодировка указана вида cp1252, ее нужно сменить на utf-8

Comment: Можно поподробнее, мне нужно сменить кодировку файле который я собираю в exe или какой-то другой?

Comment: Можешь свой код прикрепить?

Comment: Конечно, вот он: print('g')

Comment: Вероятно проблема в том, что имя активного пользователя на русском указано.